# Why Java DefaultTableModel use Vector?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I know we have to use AWT thread for all table model update operations. Under the single AWT thread, any table model will be thread-safe. Why DefaultTableModel picks thread-safe Vector as its data stucture, which slower than other data structures like ArrayList?

Comment: did you measure the "slower"? Assumed-only (mis-)performance has exactly zero performance-impact :-)

Answer (score 7):

Swing first appeared before Java 1.2, so before `ArrayList` was available. Unfortunately, the API for `DefaultTableModel` *exposes* the fact that it uses `Vector`, so changing it now would be backwardly incompatible.

This is exactly the kind of reason for thinking about encapsulation carefully - it lets you change the internals later on. (Admittedly getting serialization right would have been interesting, but that's a story for another day...)

Answer (score 5):

Swing was available for, but not included in, Java 1.1. `List`/`ArrayList` was introduced in 1.2. Pity, because Swing could have done with a bit of extra time before locking down the API.

Answer (score 2):

The reason has already been explained above (Swing existed before java.util Collections library).

**The bottom line** is: never use `DefaultTableModel` but rather build your own (based on `AbstractTableModel`).

Comment: I disagree with the advice of never use DefaultTableModel.  Only re-invent the wheel with AbstractTableModel when you have to.  There are plenty of cases that using DefaultTableModel will not hurt.

Comment: @jzd Well, if you like defining a Vector of Vector of Object or an Object[][], then it's up to you, but you lack type-safety and code readability. In my whole life of Swing developer, I have never used DefaultTableModel (except for stupid code samples). Coding your own is straightforward, while using GlazedList does a much better work altogether.

Comment: @jzd, @jfpoilpret - mostly a matter of taste, there're pros and cons for both :-) It's not trivial (for starters) to implement a robust model. Most of the time it doesn't hurt, only looks sooo retro to simply use the default. My bottom line: use what is available until a custom implementation is really needed.

Comment: @jzd, i disagree with your advice :) A model should contain data in a usable domain specific format. A Vector of varying types, is not a proper model object.

Comment: @jfpoilpret, I agree if you don't have Object arrays or Vectors then DefaultTableModel is less appealing. My point that "never use" is too strong of a statement.

Comment: @kleopatra. How hard is a javabean? Frankly i think that maintaining a model object in a Vector to be significantly more difficult then a java bean.

Comment: @jzd OK, I could have said "avoid using it like the plague for your own sanity" ;-)

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy javabean (aside: assuming you mean a bean as of the beans spec, not the crippled construct used for java on a web-page) or not, it's not hard as such, it's the nofication that most custom implementations get wrong ;-)

Comment: I also recommend to create custom models, based on a list of MyObjects (OO approach) rather than using a vector of vector of Objects (data centric approach). Here is a simple read-only sample, I wrote some time ago:
http://puces-samples.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/puces-samples/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java?revision=13&view=markup

Comment: hey, hey... if many of us start leaving DefaultTableModel, and start using AbstractTableModel, then be prepared that the RemoveRow method is not easy! :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the [`DefaultTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) class was actually developed before [The Collections Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) (which includes the [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class) was introduced in Java -- therefore, the `DefaultTableModel` class wasn't implemented using the classes introduced as part of The Collections Framework.

Here are a few facts:

- [`DefaultTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) was introduced in Java 1.2
- [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) was introduced in Java 1.2
- [`Vector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) was introduced in JDK 1.0

Furthermore, the use of a `Vector` as the underlying data structure by the `DefaultTableModel` class is an implementation detail, as the [`TableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface itself doesn't rely on the usage of a `Vector`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I wish they could change the implementation in later version.

Comment: @user729309 As a matter of fact, I'm not sure changing it to ArrayList instead of Vector would bring **dramatic** increase in performance (except if you have loads of rows but in this case, you already have a performance -and memory- problem anyway).

Comment: @jfpoilpret - without measuring it brings exactly zero increase ;-)